# cloudera link error while run sqoop list database command

Tags: mysql, cloudera, sqoop

Am trying to run the below command in cloudera and getting link failure error. I have tried to restart mysqld service too, no use. Kindly some one help friends.

Code and error:

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sqoop list-databases --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306"  --username=retail_dba --password=cloudera

Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
17/09/22 09:45:59 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.10.0
17/09/22 09:45:59 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/09/22 09:45:59 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
**17/09/22 09:46:16 ERROR manager.CatalogQueryManager: Failed to list databases
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure**

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

Answer (score 2):

Download mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar and copy it into the sqoop lib folder then try to run the sqoop import as follows:

```
sqoop list-databases \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306" \
--username=retail_dba \
--password=cloudera
```